# What is the length of the keyboard enter and exit animation on WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation, keyboard

There appears to be no documentation on this. I'd like an play an equivalent length animation while the keyboard is entering and exiting. Being even slightly off makes the animation look very awkward.

Thanks again.

Comment: Not sure there's any source code available for it. What you could do is time it yourself manually to get a ball park figure and then manually tweak your animation length to match that.

Comment: That's what I have been trying to do, but it appears there is a slight easing function is used, thus making it near impossible to nail down all the parameters to match the animation.

Comment: Are you trying to match the animation style as well, or just the animation length? If the latter, then the easing function shouldn't matter since you only need to estimate the start and end time.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I am trying to match the style as well. I basically want a banner to always appear at screen position (0,0). When any textbox gets focus and the keyboard starts to come up I need to animate the banner object down as the keyboard slides up to make it appear as if the banner is always locked to (0,0). I couldn't think of another way to do this. It appears the keyboard lives in the Phone Shell and is completely inaccessible. Is there a way to do object layout in the Shell layer?

Comment: The built in texting application does this very thing. If you look at the top where it has some text like "John Doe, Text". That will stay locked to the top of the screen even when you bring up the keyboard to type a text.

Comment: Interesting question. Just a shot in the dark but you could put the banner in a separate container from the LayoutRoot. When something has Focus, remove the container's Transform.

Comment: I don't know the animation length, but the Amazon Kindle application does what the OP is asking to very good effect (tapping on the book while in "reading mode")

Comment: Ignore my last comment, the Kindle animation is timed with the menu, not the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, it's not documented. I think the best choice you have is to start with a guess (<strike>400ms</strike> 300ms seems like a good start to me) and tweak it until the difference is unnoticable.

**Updated:** I thought you were referring to the menu animation time, not the keyboard.